# How to detect the host OS from container?

Tags: docker, containers

While you are on the container terminal, how can you detect the host OS (Windows/Mac/Linux)?

I need to access it, even if I can send it as a dynamic env variable. Docker does not work exactly the same in all host OSs. e.g. File permissions are not mapped from windows to Linux when you mount a volume.

One heuristic can be mounting a file with permission other than 777 and if that permission is retained you can realise that the OS is not Windows. I look for a better way.

Comment: Can you give an example of application code, that's running in a container, that needs to know this?  Typically a container will give a consistent environment to its application independent of the host OS or distribution, and you want to minimize rather than exploit differences.

Comment: there is an example already in the question.

Comment: If you read this article https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-56-volume-mounting-ssh-keys-into-a-docker-container the author suggests to set the  permission of the  files that are mounted from Windows to the manually, but if the host is not Windows I prefer to just leave the file permission as is and not modify them.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. The point of containers is to abstract that information away from you because it isn't relevant.

Comment: I need to access it, even if I can send as dynamic env variables. Docker does not work exactly the same in all host OSs. e.g. File permissions are not mapped from windows to Linux when you mount a volume.

Comment: Then you should provide that information on the commandline invocation for use with a `getenv()` call inside your container.